# .htaccess does not open index

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I decided to do a little rewriting on my site.
Currently, I have this htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

What it does is that you can enter .php documents without adding the .php extension
, like

you can access *folder/file.php* by typing *folder/file* into the url bar.

However, now I realised that index.php is not working anymore.

If I try to enter the index via `folder/index.php` or `folder/index`, it works fine but it does not open it when typing just `folder/`

What rule am I missing here?

Sorry I'm not used to htaccess. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...but it does not open it when typing just folder/

Presumably you just get a 404?

You should also exclude directories from being internally rewritten. For example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

So now, when you type `example.com/folder/` (which maps to a *directory*, not a *file*), it won't be rewritten by the above directives and mod_dir will be able to load the `DirectoryIndex`.

Aside: There is an additional caveat with having the same content accessible by all these different URLs (eg. `folder/index.php`, `folder/index` and `folder/`) - you now have a potential *duplicate content* issue. Be sure to be consistent in you internal linking, include canonical meta tags and redirect if it becomes a problem.

Comment: plus one for duplicate content warning